# Multiselect html form custom separator

Tags: html, forms

I need to pass a value in option multiselect to action where I have 
/?_sft_category=SELECTION1,SELECTION2

```
<form medhod="post" action="/?_sft_category=">
<option value="SELECTION1">Selection text 1</option>
<option value="SELECTION2">selection text 2</option>
```

This turns to something like /?_sft_category=1/?_sft_category=2

Please help

Comment: I need that ","